# Convert factor containing AM/PM to 24 hours HH:MM time format using R programming

Tags: r, time

I use R.

It should not be a difficult thing at all. All I am missing is the sintax I guess.
I have a data frame named 'twyrs' and in that one column is a time column. 
when I do  class(twyrs$TIME) it's showing 'factor'.
The time is in the format "9:00 PM","00:15 AM" and so on.

All i need is the time to be in the format "21:00" and "00:15" format respectively. That is 24 hours HH MM format. I dont have any seconds attached to my time. Only Hours and mins.

I have tried

library(chron)
x <- chron(times=twyrs$TIME)

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your "00:15 AM" time strings. Use `gsub("00:", "12:", x, fixed = TRUE)` to substitute `00` with `12`. Then you can do this:

```
x <- factor(c("9:00 PM","00:15 AM", "12:15 AM" ))
y <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%I:%M %p", tz = "GMT") #read help("strptime")

library(chron)
times(strftime(y, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"))
#[1] 21:00:00 <NA>     00:15:00
```

Comment: The only modification (Not manfdate, good to have) I would like to have the time format of Y to be like 09:45  and not like 09:45:00

Comment: It was not clear to me what kind of object you want. If you just need a character string (and not a chron object), you can simply use `strftime(y, format = "%H:%M", tz = "GMT")`